# Обязательное поле прикрепление файла

Tags: html

Как сделать так, чтобы при отправке формы нужно обязательно прикрепить файл?

Comment: Добавьте в форму <input type="file" required="true">
Дополнительно перед submit можно проверить это поле на заполненность с помощью JavaScript

Comment: вот можно использовать http://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method/

Comment: пример http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/6pt1tkdu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В HTML5 достаточно просто required

```
document.getElementById("myFile").required = true;
```

Описание: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_required.asp

Работающий пример: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_fileupload_required2